# AWS ses throws NoSuchMethodException (kotliin)

Tags: kotlin, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, okhttp, amazon-ses

**When i try this**

```
SesClient {
                region = s3Region
                credentialsProvider = provider
            }.use {
                it.sendEmail(request)
            }
```

**it throws**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'okhttp3.Request$Builder okhttp3.Request$Builder.tag(kotlin.reflect.KClass, java.lang.Object)'
```

I think it's because of dependency, but it couldn't be fixed by a lot of modifications.

When I Googled, there was someone who had a similar problem, and I tried to copy the method, but it was no use. Below is the link.
[https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-kotlin/issues/765](https://stackoverflow.com)

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    kapt("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

    // QueryDsl
    kapt("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta")
    api("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta")

    // Blaze Persistence
    api("com.blazebit:blaze-persistence-core-api-jakarta:1.6.8")
    api("com.blazebit:blaze-persistence-core-impl-jakarta:1.6.8")
    api("com.blazebit:blaze-persistence-integration-hibernate-6.0:1.6.8")
    api("com.blazebit:blaze-persistence-integration-querydsl-expressions-jakarta:1.6.8")

    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

    implementation("com.github.gavlyukovskiy:p6spy-spring-boot-starter:1.8.1")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.14.1")
    implementation("com.eaio.uuid:uuid:3.2")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging:1.2.4.RELEASE")

    implementation("aws.sdk.kotlin:s3:0.30.1-beta")
    implementation("aws.sdk.kotlin:ses:0.30.1-beta")

// When I added this dependency, okhttp 4.10.0 version was added too. But why?
// can it be the reason?
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.11") 

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")

    implementation("org.trimou:trimou-extension-spring4-mvc:2.3.0.Final")

    testFixturesImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5-jvm:5.5.5")
    testFixturesImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core-jvm:5.5.5")
    testFixturesImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-extensions-jvm:5.5.5")
    testFixturesImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-property-jvm:5.5.5")
    testFixturesImplementation("io.kotest.extensions:kotest-extensions-spring:1.1.2")
    testFixturesImplementation("org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc")
    testFixturesImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test")
    testFixturesImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testFixturesImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
        exclude(module = "mockito-core")
    }

    runtimeOnly("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j")
}
```